# Problem calculating Higher Time Frame trends rsi2>rsi2[] on 1 hr chart

Tags: pine-script

I have spent numerous days researching and trying to write a piece of pine script code that will reference a higher timeframe (e.g - 2D) on a 1 hour chart with the ability to calculate the trend direction of that indicator (Bullish/Up or bearish/Down), to then gain the ability to script into a strategy to execute buy orders based on the 1 hour indicator only if the 2D trend is up/bullish etc.

The challenge is the 2D data is compiled every 48 hours, so to do a rsi2 > rsi2[48] will only reference that specific data point 48 hours ago, which is likely to be NaN depending on the if the hour coincides with the 48 hour data point or not. Therefore many buy triggers based on the 60 min TF are missed as the corresponding 2D data is NaN.

I have therefore attempted an array which references a history of data points for the required period (48 for 2D), thanks to info posted on this site and Pine Script Documentation, which i thought I got it working, but realize it is not accurate.

I temporarily use the background color script to highlight if the code is correctly identifying the downtrend and uptrend. It is not accurate and there are a number of gaps in the background color over a trending period.

I cannot find any forum questions/answers related to this question...hence why i post here and it may also help others in future

Below is the specific code related to the question.

I would be so grateful if someone can help me with this and point me in the right direction with where i am going wrong with this code or may know a script format which will work as required......
Thankyou so much :-)

```
study(title="RSI MTF TV", shorttitle="RSI MTF TV", overlay=false)

source = close
lengthRsi1 = input(8, minval=8)
lengthRsi2 = input(8, minval=8)
OverSold = input(25)
OverBought = input(75)
//I am using the 1 Hr Chart Resolution
Res1 = input(title='Resolution 1', type=input.resolution, defval="")
Res2 = input(title='Resolution 2', type=input.resolution, defval="2D")

rsi1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, Res1, rsi(source, lengthRsi1), barmerge.gaps_on)
rsi2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, Res2, rsi(source, lengthRsi2), barmerge.gaps_on)

plot(rsi1, title="Rsi 1", color=color.aqua, linewidth=1)
plot(rsi2, title="Rsi 2", color=color.purple, linewidth=1)

//RSI Trend
rsi2UpTrend = rsi2 > rsi2[48]
rsi2DwnTrend = rsi2 < rsi2[48]

f_rsi2Trend(_cond, _lookback) =>
    bool _rsi2Trend = false
    for i = 1 to _lookback
        if _cond[i]
            _rsi2Trend := true
    _rsi2Trend

rsi2UpTrend48 = f_rsi2Trend(rsi2UpTrend, 48)

rsi2DwnTrend48 = f_rsi2Trend(rsi2DwnTrend, 48)

//Plot Backgroud
bgcolor(rsi2DwnTrend48 ? color.red :na, transp = 70)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fixnan()` to fill `rsi2` with the previous non NaN value. eg `rsi2UpTrend = fixnan(rsi2) > ....`

But it may be better to wrap what you're doing in a function :

```
f_rsiTrend(_src, _len) =>
    _rsi = rsi(_src, _len)
    _trendUp = _rsi >= _rsi[1]
    _trendUp
    
rsi2Trend = security(syminfo.tickerid, Res2, f_rsiTrend(source, lengthRsi2))
```

Comment: Hi there RumpyPumpyDumpy ..... thankyou so much....yep...that did it. I am still working and refining it - but i can see that wrapping it in a function has helped....plus also improved my understanding of Functions....which i am still on a learning curve about. Much appreciated :-) ....